# Gitlab CI/CD error: nested array of strings up to 10 levels deep

Tags: amazon-s3, gitlab-ci, bucket

I am writing a gitlab ci/cd to put encryption on the s3 bucket . I am following the [official documentation link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-encryption.html) from AWS. But while running it on gitlab ci/cd pipeline, I am getting this error on the editor.

```
This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:onestage:script config should be a string or a nested array of strings up to 10 levels deep.
```

The error line is as follow:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket bucket-name --server-side-encryption-configuration '{"Rules": [{"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {"SSEAlgorithm": "AES256"}}]}'
```

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#syntax-is-incorrect-in-scripts-that-use- may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Joachim-isaksson for your help. It indeed helped me to solve this error. Meanwhile, I am putting the code to solve this error that i have used.

```
'aws s3api put-bucket-encryption --bucket my-bucket --server-side-encryption-configuration "{\"Rules\": [{\"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault\": {\"SSEAlgorithm\": \"AES256\"}}]}"'
```